# Custom Button for Convert Lead with Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-button, leads, lead-conversion

I would like to prevent users from converting a lead if some fields are missing (State, country, company type) - I don't want to use standard validation, as I want the users to remain on the same screen and add details if needed.
I added the code below for the custom button. Do I need to add anything to it?

```
var state = "{!Lead.State}";
var country = "{!Lead.Country}";
var type = "{!Lead.Company_Type__c}";
if (state == '' || country == '' || type == '') 
{ 
alert('missing fields, please complete'); 
} 
else 
{ 
window.location = 'https://cs9.salesforce.com/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}'; 

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Does the button perform as desired? Right now this is looking more as a JavaScript validation question and not much of a Salesforce question and is in danger of being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is clean. Only one thing: use relative URL instead of absolute, so you dont need to adjust the link to the current org after deployment:

> <strike>https://cs9.salesforce.com</strike>/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}

Comment: Thanks @sergey, just one minor question...why I don't have to add the following "!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")}" to the code? I saw this in several examples (maybe it's for creation / update records?)

Comment: @ItayB This is an Salesforce AJAX Toolkit typographical convention. It will be used (like you said) for the CRUD operations. You can read the docs here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm#when_to_use_ajax